# Why messages remain in SQS after processing through lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have written the following lambda to move messages from "queueA" to "queueB".

```
async function reprocess_messages(fromQueue, toQueue) {
    try {
        const response1 = await sqs.send(new GetQueueUrlCommand({ QueueName: fromQueue }));
        const response2 = await sqs.send(new GetQueueUrlCommand({ QueueName: toQueue }));

        const fromQueueUrl = response1.QueueUrl;
        const toQueueUrl = response2.QueueUrl;

        let completed = false;
        while (!completed) {
            completed = await moveMessage(toQueueUrl, fromQueueUrl);
            // console.log(status);
        }
        // console.log(completed);
        return completed;

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}


async function moveMessage(toQueueUrl, fromQueueUrl) {
    try {
        const receiveMessageParams = {
            MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
            MessageAttributeNames: ["Messsages"],
            QueueUrl: fromQueueUrl,
            VisibilityTimeout: 2,
            WaitTimeSeconds: 0,
        };

        const receiveData = await sqs.send(new ReceiveMessageCommand(receiveMessageParams));
        // console.log(receiveData);

        if (!receiveData.Messages) {
            console.log("finished");
            return true;
        }

        const messages = [];
        receiveData.Messages.forEach(msg => {
            messages.push({ body: msg["Body"], receiptHandle: msg["ReceiptHandle"] });
        });

        const sendMsg = async ({ body, receiptHandle }) => {
            const sendMessageParams = {
                MessageBody: body,
                QueueUrl: toQueueUrl
            };
            await sqs.send(new SendMessageCommand(sendMessageParams));
            // console.log("Success, message sent. MessageID: ", sentData.MessageId);
            return "Success";
        };

        const deleteMsg = async ({ body, receiptHandle }) => {
            const deleteMessageParams = {
                QueueUrl: fromQueueUrl,
                ReceiptHandle: receiptHandle
            };
            await sqs.send(new DeleteMessageCommand(deleteMessageParams));
            // console.log("Message deleted", deleteData);
            return "Deleted";
        };

        const sent = await Promise.all(messages.map(sendMsg));
        // console.log(sent);
        await Promise.all(messages.map(deleteMsg));
        // console.log(deleted);
        console.log(sent.length);
        return false;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


export const handler = async function (event, context) {
    console.log("Invoking lambda");
    const response = await reprocess_messages("queueA", "queueB");
    console.log(response);
}
```

For testing it, I populated queueA with 500 messages and invoked the lambda. After the completion I see that there were no errors in the logs but 16 messages were still remaining in queueA.

[image: Queue Messages]

Also, as per the following lambda logs there mustn't be any messages in queueA as it printed `finished` which is the condition to check if there aren't any message received from sqs.

[image: lambda logs]

lambda config :

- Timeout : 2 min
- Memory : 256 MB

lambda report :
REPORT RequestId: de685eaf-9787-45f4-b800-78d3a80b4c95  Duration: 11094.61 ms   Billed Duration: 11095 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 122 MB Init Duration: 470.62 ms

I am not sure why there are messages remaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a message is read from an Amazon SQS queue, the message is made 'invisible' so that it is not processed by another worker.

If the message is not **deleted** within the 'invisibility period', then the message will **reappear on the queue**. This is because Amazon SQS assumes that the worker processing the message has failed, and that the message needs to be reprocessed.

Therefore, your code should:

- **Read** messages from the Queue A
- **Send** the messages to Queue B
- **Delete** the messages from Queue A (but only after they have been written to Queue B, to avoid potential loss of messages)

See: [DeleteMessageCommand | SQS Client - AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sqs/classes/deletemessagecommand.html)